# Add extra responsive styles in Bootstrap 3 using pure CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I add extra responsive styles in Bootstrap 3?

I'm trying this, but it's not working:

```
/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { 
  .container {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

The styles just aren't appearing. Do I need to replace `@screen-lg-min` with a raw number?

I'm using pure CSS, not LESS or SASS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to use the actual width (ie: `1200px`)

```
/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  .container {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

The `@...` parameters are using less syntax, not CSS.

Test on Bootply: http://bootply.com/95146